# Nicest, efficient way to get result tuple of sequence items fulfilling and not fulfilling condition

Tags: python, filter, generator, data-partitioning

*(This is professional best practise/ pattern interest, not home work request)*

- **INPUT**: any unordered sequence or generator **items**, function **myfilter(item)** returns True if filter condition is fulfilled
- **OUTPUT**: **(filter_true, filter_false)** tuple of sequences of
  original type which contain the
  elements partitioned according to
  filter in original sequence order.

How would you express this without doing double filtering, or should I use double filtering? Maybe filter and loop/generator/list comprehencion with `next` could be answer?

Should I take out the requirement of keeping the type or just change requirement giving tuple of tuple/generator result, I can not return easily generator for generator input, or can I? *(The requirements are self-made)*

Here test of best candidate at the moment, offering two streams instead of tuple

```
import itertools as it
from sympy.ntheory import isprime as myfilter

mylist = xrange(1000001,1010000,2)
left,right = it.tee((myfilter(x), x) for x in mylist)
filter_true = (x for p,x in left if p)
filter_false = (x for p,x in right if not p)

print 'Hundred primes and non-primes odd  numbers'
print  '\n'.join( " Prime %i, not prime %i" %
                  (next(filter_true),next(filter_false))
                  for i in range(100))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it which only calls `myfilter` once for each item and will also work if `mylist` is a generator

```
import itertools as it
left,right = it.tee((myfilter(x), x) for x in mylist)
filter_true = (x for p,x in left if p)
filter_false = (x for p,x in right if not p)
```

Comment: Looks nice! My idea was to filter left and right to (left, None) or (None, right) and filter the left and right with ifilter out of Nones. But you realized that only one side need to be `None`d.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that your probleme is not memory but cpu, myfilter is heavy and you don't want to iterate and filter the original dataset twice. Here are some **single pass** ideas :

The simple and versatile version (memoryvorous) :

```
filter_true=[]
filter_false=[]
for item in  items:
    if myfilter(item):
        filter_true.append(item)
    else:
        filter_false.append(item)
```

The memory friendly version : (doesn't work with generators (unless used with list(items)))

```
while items:
    item=items.pop()
    if myfilter(item):
        filter_true.append(item)
    else:
        filter_false.append(item)
```

The generator friendly version :

```
while True:
    try:
        item=next(items)
        if myfilter(item):
            filter_true.append(item)
        else:
            filter_false.append(item)  
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Works well if it's acceptable to store all data as lists, but sometimes generators are better.

Comment: Input could be for example tarfile.open('backup.tar.bz2', 'r:bz2') with 6 Gigabytes backup file. I only want one item from either type of input, say jpg files and other files.

Comment: Your generator would still need to be run until end and produce list by append so it is list version. Taking values by pop is sometimes possible replacement for generator, made one post like that myself once. That would be however filter_true.pop(0) or filter_false.pop(0), pop() pops from end of list and you are messing up the order of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (but less efficient) is to [`tee`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) the iterable and filter both of them:

```
import itertools
left, right = itertools.tee( mylist )
filter_true = (x for x in left if myfilter(x))
filter_false = (x for x in right if myfilter(x))
```

This is less efficient than the optimal solution, because `myfilter` will be called repeatedly for each element. That is, if you have tested an element in `left`, you shouldn't have to re-test it in `right` because you already know the answer. If you require this optimisation, it shouldn't be hard to implement: have a look at the implementation of `tee` for clues. You'll need a deque for each returned iterable which you stock with the elements of the original sequence that should go in it but haven't been asked for yet.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet will be constructing two separate generators:

```
filter_true = (x for x in mylist if myfilter(x))
filter_false = (x for x in mylist if not myfilter(x))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work for lists, not generators -- you don't get two chances to iterate through a generator.